# What kind of aggregation layout style does Spotify use on their Facebook timeline app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

It's like a half single item/list thing. It looks slick and I want to reproduce it but I can't figure it out. Maybe it's something special that Facebook let Spotify do on their own?

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the Open Graph / Timeline beta, and it is [available to all developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/). These are called "[aggregations](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/define-units/)".

Comment: yes i understand that, hence "aggregation" and "timeline" in the question title. I would like to know WHICH aggregation spotify uses though. Item? List? etc...